# How to get back the missing monitor option in High Sierra's menubar?

Tags: high-sierra, menu-bar

When plugging in an external monitor on my MacBook-pro Sierra I could set the monitor options to show up on the menu bar. That works like a charm.

Since the upgrade to High Sierra, I am not able to get this option again.

I connect an HDMI monitor via Apple Adapter to USB-C and I am unable to find a way to enable this option.

Other colleagues don't have this issue with exactly the same setup.

Answer (score 2):

Open System Preferences → Displays and enable ‘Show mirroring options in the menu bar when available’.

This should add a menu item [image: AirPlay menu] for the AirPlay menu even without an external display connected, and when an external display is connected you can use this to switch between mirror and extend.

Comment: true, but the icon doesn't appear even this option is checked. I should mention that. But this is exactly the issue.

Comment: "Should add a menu item"  - Should, but doesn't.